# How to replace commas with a new line in the same cell in multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame created using xlsx. file containing in the picture. Two of the columns have a list. Those two columns I want to take out the commas and replace them with a new line without creating new rows.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHPSU.png)

I tried the following code
df2 = df2[['Business Process', 'Business Term','Definition', 'Column', 'Table', 'Database', 'Note', 'BWise Controls', 'Financial Statement Line Item/Footnote',
'Process ID', 'Control Information', 'Product Type', 'Sensitivity Classification', 'Criticality Classification', 'Criticality Type', 'Identified Quarter', 'ID']]

df2 ['BWise Controls'] = df2['BWise Controls'].replace(lambda v: v.replace(', ', '\n') if isinstance(v, str) else v)

df2.to_excel('mfCDE.xlsx')

This is what I wanted in the picture attached.[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOcqw.png)

But it separated out all the columns with commas, including the Definition column, which I don't want the commas taken out.

I only want BWise Controls and Financial Statement Line Item/Footnote columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.